# Domain and range of locus formed from parametric equations

Tags: parametric, locus

\begin{cases}
x = t^2 + 2t\\
y = 4(t+1)^2
\end{cases}

Determine the cartesian equation of the locus?
What is the domain of the locus?

Note: I have found the cartesian equation:
$y=4x+4$
I am just not sure if their is a restriction on the domain.

Comment: Cartesian equation is polynomial @LeeWarren  Welcome to MSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x = t^2 + 2t = (t+1)^2 - 1 \ge -1 \,\forall t \in \Bbb R$$
Hence the required domain is $[-1,\infty)$.

Comment: Can 't' be a complex number though?

Comment: @LeeWarren This is a good question !  I think that this is a high school question, so I assume that $x \in \Bbb R$.  If you allow $t$ to be complex, then you may apply the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to say that the domain of $x$ is $\Bbb C$, since $\Bbb C$ *can't* have any algebraic extension other than itself.  However, I think this may not be something that you want, so I assume that all variables are *real*.